# LESSCHARSET=utf-8 less doesn't seem to work

Tags: utf-8, unix

I'm trying to view a UTF-8 text file/stream in `less`, and even if I invoke it like this:

```
cat file | LESSCHARSET=utf-8 less
```

the non-ASCII compatible UTF-8 characters don't display correctly. Instead, their hex values appear highlighted in brackets, e.g. `<F4>`.

The reading the same text in vim with UTF-8 encoding poses no problems. So I'm thinking something is wrong with the way I'm invoking `less`.

My `locale` output is the following

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My less version is the one installed by XCode on OSX Leopard:

```
$ less --version | sed 's/^/    /'
less 394
Copyright (C) 1984-2005 Mark Nudelman

less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
For information about the terms of redistribution, 
see the file named README in the less distribution.
Homepage: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less
```

`locale -a | grep US | sed 's/^/    /'` outputs the following:

```
en_AU.US-ASCII
en_CA.US-ASCII
en_GB.US-ASCII
en_NZ.US-ASCII
en_US
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US.ISO8859-15
en_US.US-ASCII
en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. What does the `locale` command output?  Is it a UTF-8 locale?
2. Are you sure your *terminal* is set to display UTF-8?
   Does `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'` produce the € (euro) sign?
3. Is the locale that you have set even installed on the system?  Is it
   present in the list that `locale -a` outputs?
4. What version of `less` are you using?  (Run `less --version` to find out.)
   *Really*, **really** old versions did not even support `LESSCHARSET`.  This
   is less likely to be the case, because I have a Debian "sarge" system with
   `less` version 382, and it does not even need LESSCHARSET if the locale is
   set correctly.

Comment: LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Yes, `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'` does produce the euro sign.

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure this out for me. I answered your questions above.

Comment: @dan Just to check, `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'` prints the euro sign, but `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac' | less` prints a box?

Comment: actually, `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac' | less` works correctly, and displays a euro sign. 

This helped me figure out part of the problem. The file I'm testing was actually encoded in latin-1, and I was incorrectly looking at the Vim `encoding` value rather than the Vim `fileencoding` value to determine its encoding.

Doing `LESSCHARSET=latin1 less file` now shows `?` diamonds where the ü character should be. I guess that's as it should be?

Comment: In my case, the answers are: 1 -> yes, everything utf-8 locale, 2 -> I see the € sign, 3 -> yes it is, 4 -> version 444. But I should add `file` says it's `UTF-8 Unicode English text`, and that `echo -e 'Ꝍ' | less` shows `<U+A74C>`. Why can't I see the `Ꝍ` only inside `less`?

Comment: @RubenCaro In that case I suspect a bug in `less`, or it may be that your locale definition files are too old for that character from Unicode 5.1.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that your file isn't UTF8 but rather ISO8859.  (Is the <F4> character supposed to be a 'ô'?)

Start an xterm with `LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1 xterm`. Then verify the locale (the output of `locale` should be something like en_US.ISO-8859-1).  Then use less to view the file.  Does it display correctly?

Note that it isn't enough to just use `LESSCHARSET=iso8859` without starting a new terminal.  `LESSCHARSET` tells less to think that the terminal can interpret iso8859, but your terminal probably displays UTF8, since the euro sign displays correctly.  But as \xf4 isn't a valid utf8 character, the terminal will probably show something like '�'.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem for me. The terminal had a different output encoding than less. I wish there was a way to tell less to read the file in one encoding and output its contents in another (or the default, such as that of `$LANG`!).

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS a charset name have to be in upper case:

```sh
bash-4.4$ less --version
less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman

bash-4.4$ LESSCHARSET=cp1251 less
invalid charset name

bash-4.4$ LESSCHARSET=CP1251 less
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
```

[Here](https://github.com/unofficial-mirror/less/blob/7442f4839d9648b48d38b276965386da2e4b88de/charset.c#L42) I found a list of charsets:

```c
{ "ascii",          NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.b" },
{ "utf-8",          &utf_mode,  "8bcccbcc18b95.b126.bb" },
{ "iso8859",        NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.33b." },
{ "latin3",         NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.33b5.b8.b15.b4.b12.b18.b12.b." },
{ "arabic",         NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.33b.3b.7b2.13b.3b.b26.5b19.b" },
{ "greek",          NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.33b4.2b4.b3.b35.b44.b" },
{ "greek2005",      NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.33b14.b35.b44.b" },
{ "hebrew",         NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.33b.b29.32b28.2b2.b" },
{ "koi8-r",         NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.b." },
{ "KOI8-T",         NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.b8.b6.b8.b.b.5b7.3b4.b4.b3.b.b.3b." },
{ "georgianps",     NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.3b11.4b12.2b." },
{ "tcvn",           NULL,       "b..b...bcccbccbbb7.8b95.b48.5b." },
{ "TIS-620",        NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.b.4b.11b7.8b." },
{ "next",           NULL,       "8bcccbcc18b95.bb125.bb" },
{ "dos",            NULL,       "8bcccbcc12bc5b95.b." },
{ "windows-1251",   NULL,       "8bcccbcc12bc5b95.b24.b." },
{ "windows-1252",   NULL,       "8bcccbcc12bc5b95.b.b11.b.2b12.b." },
{ "windows-1255",   NULL,       "8bcccbcc12bc5b95.b.b8.b.5b9.b.4b." },
{ "ebcdic",         NULL,       "5bc6bcc7bcc41b.9b7.9b5.b..8b6.10b6.b9.7b9.8b8.17b3.3b9.7b9.8b8.6b10.b.b.b." },
{ "IBM-1047",       NULL,       "4cbcbc3b9cbccbccbb4c6bcc5b3cbbc4bc4bccbc191.b" },
{ NULL, NULL, NULL }
```

and a list of corresponding aliases for them:

```c
{ "UTF-8",          "utf-8" },
{ "ANSI_X3.4-1968", "ascii" },
{ "US-ASCII",       "ascii" },
{ "latin1",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-1",     "iso8859" },
{ "latin9",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-15",    "iso8859" },
{ "latin2",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-2",     "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-3",     "latin3" },
{ "latin4",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-4",     "iso8859" },
{ "cyrillic",       "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-5",     "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-6",     "arabic" },
{ "ISO-8859-7",     "greek" },
{ "IBM9005",        "greek2005" },
{ "ISO-8859-8",     "hebrew" },
{ "latin5",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-9",     "iso8859" },
{ "latin6",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-10",    "iso8859" },
{ "latin7",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-13",    "iso8859" },
{ "latin8",         "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-14",    "iso8859" },
{ "latin10",        "iso8859" },
{ "ISO-8859-16",    "iso8859" },
{ "IBM437",         "dos" },
{ "EBCDIC-US",      "ebcdic" },
{ "IBM1047",        "IBM-1047" },
{ "KOI8-R",         "koi8-r" },
{ "KOI8-U",         "koi8-r" },
{ "GEORGIAN-PS",    "georgianps" },
{ "TCVN5712-1",     "tcvn" },
{ "NEXTSTEP",       "next" },
{ "windows",        "windows-1252" }, /* backward compatibility */
{ "CP1251",         "windows-1251" },
{ "CP1252",         "windows-1252" },
{ "CP1255",         "windows-1255" },
{ NULL, NULL }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the command `file file.txt`.   If, for example, the output is "ISO-8859 English text" then change the encoding of the file from ISO-8859 to UTF-8 via the command `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 -o testfile.txt file.txt`.   If `less testfile.txt` displays correctly, finish with `mv testfile.txt file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

`less -r` displays the file correctly for me.

```
 -r or --raw-control-chars
              Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.  The default is
              to  display  control  characters  using  the caret notation; for
              example, a control-A (octal 001) is displayed as "^A".  Warning:
              when the -r option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual
              appearance of the screen (since this depends on how  the  screen
              responds to each type of control character).  Thus, various dis-
              play problems may result, such as long lines being split in  the
              wrong place.
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
f='path/to/file/filename.extension'; LESSCHARSET=`file -b --mime-encoding ${f}|tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` less ${f}
```