# Git messages with french accents

Tags: git, utf-8, character-encoding

I use to commit my personnal projects with french messages, including UTF-8 accents.

I was working on these projects on a Linux Arch install, and then pulled them on another new Arch install.

But now when I want to look at the git log of one of these projects, it doesn't render the french accents correctly.

Example with a choosen commit:

```
$ git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%h %s" 8e72413
8e72413 Ajout<C3><A9> le param<C3><A8>tre TabStop
```

But when I pipe it with `cat`, it works like a charm:

```
$ git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%h %s" 8e72413 | cat
8e72413 Ajouté le paramètre TabStop
```

It works well too when I read it using Vim, using the following similar command:

```
:r! git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%h %s" 8e72413
```

The same problem is happening if I use either `xterm` or `urxvt`, and my locale settings are well configured (as well with my old install on which I was working), with `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8`. Of course, my old Arch install is still working well, without this issue, with the same repository.

What did I miss? I really don't remember anything I could have done on my old install to make it work properly.

Comment: Look at your `less` configuration.

Comment: `less` is ruled by the `LANG` env var, no? If I use `less` to view a file with accentuated chars, it works. But `git` is still not working

Comment: You're probably right about it, because when i put `$ export GIT_PAGER=cat`, it's working again. I have to look at it, don't know yet how to setup `less` with `git`

Comment: Vaguely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114862/lesscharset-utf-8-less-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Ok, I found the problem; will put it as an answer in awhile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that my locale config was not so well configured :

```
$ locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I didn't see the important point : `LC_ALL` was not set to `fr_FR.UTF-8`.

---

EDIT:

Actually, the problem was more trivial than that : I just forgot that I added the following alias: `alias git='LANG=en_US.UTF-8 git'`

Indeed, changing the value of `LC_ALL` is not a solution.

I made this alias because `vim-fugitive` is not working well with `git` displayed in french language...

Comment: sorry for digging up that old topic, but I have exactly the same problem and can't manage to solve it. 
When I try to do `git log --graph --all --date=relative --pretty=tformat:'%Cred%h%Creset %s %Cgreen(%an %ad)%Creset'` , I get `* f79f360 Cr<C3><A9>e le serveur d'API avec les r<C3><A8>gles de validation (J.M. Cl<C3><A9>ry 22 minutes ago)`. I've tried all the solutions above, like setting all my locales to **fr_FR.UTF-8**, and even tried to use an alias : `alias git='LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 git'` but my messages still appears with these strange characters. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @jmpp If you tried all the solutions on this thread, then you should ask a new question, maybe by adding a link to here; indeed comments are not designed for this. It will also add visibility to your problem, compared to this very old thread.

Comment: Well, after other researches, I've found my solution which was to remove all the declarations in my **.zshrc** and run a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and chose "fr_FR-UTF-8" when proposed. Running the git log command after that gave me the message with the accents.